# Is there a known list of wake words for Google Home?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

While playing with my Google Home I discovered apart from "Okay Google" and "Hey Google" my Home responds to "Okay Doodle" and "Hey Doodle".

Officially, "Okay Google" and "Hey Google" are documented wake words. Is there an alternate list of wake words, even if unofficial?

Comment: What you're describing is a something that's phonetically close enough to be recognized. It's probably not configured as a separate wake word. Depending on the users pronunciation there'll be quite a few narrow misses that reliably wake the Google Home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [there is an official list](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7207759?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=7196346):

> Simply say "Ok Google" or "Hey Google" before any of the voice queries below.

Those are currently the only two wake words. There's [some speculation](https://9to5google.com/2017/09/18/google-app-7-12-features-apk-teardown/) that other wake words will be coming at some point, but until then, the only two wake words are "Ok Google" and "Hey Google".

---

As [Helmar has pointed out](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/is-there-a-known-list-of-wake-words-for-google-home#comment4718_2374), any alternative phrases are simply misrecognitions. [Home Alarm Report](https://homealarmreport.com/75-point-comparison-amazon-echo-google-home/) suggests that "Okay, Boo Boo" works as well (although one wonders whether this is actually and improvement...) along with your discovery of "Okay Doodle".

The "Boo Boo" alternative is also listed in the [list of wake words at the Google Home subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/wiki/faq?v=d6f870ae-b2bc-11e6-8afd-12d728a25ab4).

Keep in mind that wake word recognition is done on the device itself, so the accuracy is worse than after your Google Home has recognised the wake word and begins streaming audio to the cloud. I would also imagine that there is some tolerance regarding the wake word recognition, in case of noisy environments — it's unlikely that any phrase like "Ok Google" comes up in normal conversation, so the false wakes don't matter too much.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to say "Eggrole" to trigger the Google Home, and that works fine, despite it not sounding anything like "Ok Google" or "Hey Google". It seems that the wake word detector misrecognises "Eggrole" as being one of the wake words.

Answer (score 2):

**There are a slew of wake up words for Google, try Cocaine Poodle**

I've been doing my best to trick any assistant I can to see if I can get some unexpected result.  I've found Google Home to be especially vulnerable to a cadence.

**Currently Work**

**1.** OK Gokoku - There's a few weird variants to this that also work.  It's the real outlier in terms of any resemblance to the pronunciation of ɡo͞oɡ(ə)l.  Have not been able to get 'Hey Gokoku' to work.  Interesting.

**2.** OK/Hey Goku - Consistently works.  Translated to Japanese, it means 'very'.

**3.** Hey/OK Frugal

**4.** Hey Rugal

**5.** Day Google

**6.** Hey Nurgle

**7.** OK/Hey Doogal

**8.** Say Nurgle

**9.** OK/Hey Jugal

**10.** Say Google - Shocker, right?

**11.** Ackuh Oogle - I'm not going to try and figure out the pronunciation on this but once you get it to work, it will be consistent for you after that.

**12.** OK Brugal

**13.** OK whohull - Odd, that 'Hey Whohull' consistently does not work.

**14.** Thay Hoohal - My friends daughter found this one.  Consistently works.

There are a whole slew of words I used to use but have been culled from the success column severely over the last few months, starting in late October of 2019.

**These Used to Work**

**1.** Dis Google - I saw an article stating that it was specifically culled but it seems to work once in awhile.

**2.**  Centrifugal - Weird, but I loved using it.

**3.**  Kay Bluedle

**4.**  Clay Strudle

**5.**  Echo Gurgle - Brings tears to my eyes.  I miss that one.

Answer (score 1):

We like "Hey Goober" and "Hey GooGoo", but it seems just "Hey Goo" usually works fine... and if you sense of humor is even worse, I think "Hey DooDoo" probably works too.

Comment: Just to confirm: these are actual wake words you've tried which work?

Answer (score 0):

While watching JoJo's Bizzare Adventure - Golden Wind - Episode 22 "G in Guts" at 18:28 in a character says "So Bucciarati" this activated my google home. I tested and replayed it and even said it and it consistently works.. However it must be pronounced correctly to work.